# I need help playing sound on Replit

Tags: python, audio, pygame

So I'm making a game on Pygame, and I have watched tutorials on how to use Pygame for sound but for some reason no matter what I do, it doesn't play.  I am on Replit, and I have tried to use the Replit Library to but I had issues with that too.  I was wondering if I was writing something wrong or if it's just Replit or what it is.  Also If you have any tips on looping, and how to play the music at certain times that would be great.  The code below is just a little code to try to figure out how to make menus, and I was going to make the music play when I select a color.  I just tried removing

```
pygame.init()
```

but when I do, A whole bunch of stuff just does not work anymore such as fonts and it also says the mixer is not initialized.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init() 

font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 15, True)

compwin = pygame.display.set_mode((512,512))

pygame.display.set_caption("attack")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("space music.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
 
x1 = 128
y1 = 256
x2 = 256
y2 = 256
x3 = 384
y3 = 256
x4 = 251
y4 = 251
def picked():
  while run:
    pygame.time.delay(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run == False
    if white.colliderect(red):
      compwin.fill((255,0,0))
    if white.colliderect(green):
      compwin.fill((0,255,0))
    if white.colliderect(blue):
      compwin.fill((0,0,255))
      
    pygame.display.update()
    
run = True

while run:
  
  pygame.time.delay(30)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False
 
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_1]:
    x4 = x1 - 5
    y4 = y1 - 5
    
  elif keys[pygame.K_2]:
    x4 = x2 - 5
    y4 = y2 - 5
  elif keys[pygame.K_3]:
    x4 = x3 - 5
    y4 = y3 - 5
  compwin.fill((0,0,0))
  
  white = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(255,255,255), (x4,y4,42,42) )
  blue = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,0,255), (x2,y2,32,32) )
  green = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,255,0), (x3,y3,32,32) )
  red = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(255,0,0), (x1,y1,32,32) )
  
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
    picked()

  pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't play music in `pygame` on `repl` (as far as I know) because `repl` runs on a virtual machine. Apparently, this feature is planned and will be added in time. For now, I'd say to run your code on a different IDE, and that should work.

You should also look at this: https://docs.replit.com/misc/playing-audio-replit#playing-audio-on-replit

For looping audio you need to pass a `-1`: `pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = -1)`